# Refresh na tabela no success da função ajax

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte tabela onde tenho dois botões para fazer `delete` e `update`. Quando faço `delete` remove automaticamente a linha da tabela. Mas quando edito a linha e mudo de estado o utilizador continua a ver a linha, onde fica confuso porque assim não sabe as linhas que já foram editadas e as que faltam editar. Então ao mudar de estado a linha também devia de desaparecer da tabela.

Código:

```
<div id="spoiler2" class="esconde">
<table class="table table-responsive" id="employee_table2"> 
<h1 style="font-size: 30px"><strong>Pedidos de Manutenção</strong></h1>
<thead>  
<tr> 
<th>Data</th>
<th>Valência</th>
<th>Descrição</th>
<th>Colaborador</th>        
<th>Estado</th> 
<th>Ação</th>   
<th>Eliminar</th>                           
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php  do{ ?>
<tr  id="<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>">
<td><?php echo $produto2["DataRegisto"]; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $produto2["Destino"]; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $produto2["Descricao"]; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $produto2["nome"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $produto2["Estado"]; ?></td>
<td><button type="button" name="edit" data-id="<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" id="open_<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" data-target="#add_data_Modal2" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_data2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
</tr>  
<?php } while($produto2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()); ?>
</tbody>      
</table>   
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data2', function(){  
           var employee_id2 = $(this).data('id');          
           $.ajax({  
                url:"./editarmanutencao",  
                method:"POST",
                cache: false,               
                data:{employee_id2:employee_id2},               
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){

                    console.log(data);
                     $('#Id2').val(data.Id);
                     $('#Tratamento').val(data.Tratamento);
                     $('#Estado2').val(data.Estado);
                     $('#Prestador').val(data.Prestador);
                     $('#employee_id2').val(data.Id);                    
                     $('#insert2').val("Gravar");  
                     $("#add_data_Modal2").modal("show");                    
                }  
           });

      });  

function inserir_registo2()
{  

    var dadosajax = {
        'Id' : $("#Id2").val(),
        'DataTermino' : $("#DataTermino").val(),
        'Tratamento' : $("#Tratamento").val(),
        'Estado' : $("#Estado2").val(),
        'Prestador' : $("#Prestador").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: './resolucaomanutencao',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        $("#add_data_Modal2").modal("hide");
         }  
    });
}
```

Como posso retirar a linha da tabela ao mudar o estado no success do ajax?

Comment: @Sam o `$("#Id2").val()` está no modal que vai abrir com o botão de editar, este: `<td><button type="button" name="edit" data-id="<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" id="open_<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" data-target="#add_data_Modal2" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_data2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>`, devo colocar na pergunta? Na pergunta não coloquei esse modal

Comment: Se resolveu, deixa assim mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma, para remover a linha em caso de sucesso:

Adicionei esta linha antes do ajax:

```
let rowToBeRemoved =  $("#"+$("#Id2").val());
```

e dentro do ajax coloquei:

```
rowToBeRemoved.remove();
```

Código completo:

```
function inserir_registo2()
{  
    let rowToBeRemoved =  $("#"+$("#Id2").val());
    var dadosajax = {
        'Id' : $("#Id2").val(),
        'DataTermino' : $("#DataTermino").val(),
        'Tratamento' : $("#Tratamento").val(),
        'Estado' : $("#Estado2").val(),
        'Prestador' : $("#Prestador").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: './resolucaomanutencao',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        $("#add_data_Modal2").modal("hide");
        rowToBeRemoved.remove();

      }  
    });
}
```